# Cordova app stuck on splash screen after the app launched on background by geotrigger

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen, wkwebview, tls1.2

I'm developing a Cordova iOS app (**cordova-ios 4.5.4**) by using ionic (**3.20.0**) and angular (**ionic-angular ^3.9.2**).

I'm using the latest version of ionic WKWebView (**cordova-plugin-ionic-webview ^1.2.1**). I can not use apache cordova WKWebView since we are willing to support for Android.

My app populate local notifications by triggering geofences. Once a geofence is triggered, the app is launched on background by the OS if the app is not running (killed).

I'm getting the following error sometimes when the app launch on background,

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the
>   server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0241830 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
>   Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.,
>   _WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8080/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0E78BB1F-7EAA-4095-8A6D-0CBB232F0E56/XXX.app/www/index.html,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8080/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0E78BB1F-7EAA-4095-8A6D-0CBB232F0E56/XXX.app/www/index.html,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

Error occurs in the following method of `CDVWKWebViewEngine.m`,

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView*)theWebView didFailNavigation:(WKNavigation*)navigation withError:(NSError*)error
```

I have added the **App Transport Security Settings** for the **localhost** Exception Domain as,

```
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
```

Also has been set,

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
```

But still I'm getting the error. Once this is happened, the app is getting stuck on the splash screen at the next app launch by tap on the app icon or swipe a notification.

Anything else that I need to set.

Some blogs says,
***Configure a server that is enabled for the TLS 1.2 protocol.***

But I'm not sure how to configure the ionic Cordova WKWebView's local web server.

Any help is much appreciate since I'm stuck on this for a couple of week. Thanks.

---

**Updated:**

I had not added these in config.xml,

`<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*"/>` and

```
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
 <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

I added them into config.xml and built ionic ios now. But I had already added `<allow-navigation href="*" />` in config.xml.